# Java get selected value not returning correct value

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a button to transfer an item from one list to another. When the handler calls the function to identify the selected item from the list it is not returning a value which is causing the program to throw a null pointer exception. I can't figure out why this is not working does anybody have any ideas?

Inside the Controller

```
private class AddHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if(totalcredits<=120){
         **Module tmp = selectorPnl.getUnselectedModule();**
         selectorPnl.addtoSM(tmp);
         selectorPnl.rmvUSM(tmp);

         totalcredits = totalcredits+tmp.getCredits();

      } 
      else 
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exceeds credit allowance",     "Selector Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

The panel

```
 public Module getUnselectedModule()
 {
      return lstUnselectedModule.getSelectedValue();
 }
 public void addtoSM(Module list)
 {
     SM.addElement(list);
 }
 public void rmvUSM(Module list)
 {
     USM.removeElement(list);
 }
```

Edit: just had to turn my computer off and on again. Works fine now. Which means I'm even more lost as to why it wasn't before

Comment: `getSelectedValue()` returns null if there is no selected value. So, either you didn't select anything, or you selected solething in another JList. If you want to move something from one list to another, why do you get the selected value of lstUnselectedModule, but remove it from USM?

Comment: I had clicked on Element in the list and i tried all the different lists

Comment: Trying random things will not get you far. If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `lstUnselectedModule` has been instantiated within your panel, but also the `.getSelectedValue()` causes that method to return what I would assume is not a Module.  Just have it return the `lstUnselectedModule`.